# Cannot define rule priority in grako grammar for handling special tokens

Tags: python, grammar, grako, tatsu

I am trying to analyze some documents by a grammar generated via Grako that should parse simple sentences for further analysis but face some difficulties with some special tokens.

The (Grako-style) EBNF looks like:

```
abbr::str = "etc." | "feat.";
word::str = /[^.]+/;
sentence::Sentence = content:{abbr | word} ".";
page::Page = content:{sentence};
```

I used the upper grammar on following content:

> This is a sentence. This is a sentence feat. an abbrevation. I don't 
>   now feat. etc. feat. know English.

The result using a simple NodeWalker:

```
[
    'This is a sentence.',
    'This is a sentence feat.',
    'an abbrevation.',
    "I don't know feat.",
    'etc. feat. know English.'
]
```

My expectation:

```
[
    'This is a sentence.',
    'This is a sentence feat. an abbrevation.',
    "I don't know feat. etc. feat. know English."
]
```

I have no clue why this happens, especially in the last sentence where the abbreviations are part of the sentence while they are not in the prior sentences. To be clear, I want the abbr rule in the sentence definition to have a higher priority than the word rule, but I don't know how to achieve this. I played around with the negative and positive lookahead without success. I know how to achieve my expected results with regular expressions, but a context-free grammar is required for the further analysis, so I want to put everything in one grammar for the sake of readability. It has been a while since I last used grammars this way, but I don't remember running in that kind of problem. I searched a while via Google with no success, so maybe the community might share some insight.

Thanks in advance.

Code I used for testing, if required:

```
from grako.model import NodeWalker, ModelBuilderSemantics
from parser import MyParser

class MyWalker(NodeWalker):
    def walk_Page(self, node):
        content = [self.walk(c) for c in node.content]
        print(content)

    def walk_Sentence(self, node):
        return ' '.join(node.content) + "."

    def walk_str(self, node):
        return node

def main(filename: str):
    parser = MyParser(semantics=ModelBuilderSemantics())
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as src:
        result = parser.parse(src.read(), 'page')
    walker = HRBWalker()
    walker.walk(result)
```

Packages used:
Python 3.5.2
Grako 3.16.5

Comment: Did you try a trace of the parse?

Comment: Good point, I forgot that possibility entirely. I will do so tomorrow and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the regular expression you're using for the `word` rule. Regular expressions will parse over whatever you tell them to, and that regexp is eating over whitespace.

This modified grammar does what you want:

```
@@grammar:: Pages

abbr::str = "etc." | "feat.";
word::str = /[^.\s]+/;
sentence::Sentence = content:{abbr | word} ".";
page::Page = content:{sentence};

start = page ;
```

A `--trace` run revealed the problem right away.

Comment: Solves the problem entirely.